# Regex replace using Gulp

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp, regexp-replace

I am trying to achieve a regular expression replacement in my Gulp function, similar to:

```
let re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/
let str = 'John Smith'
let newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1')
console.log(newstr)
```

which returns `Smith, John`

(src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

My Gulp function in question, simplified, is

```
const stringReplace = require('gulp-string-replace'); /https://github.com/tomaszczechowski/gulp-string-replace*/
...
function imgResp() {
    return gulp.src('test.html')          
        .pipe(stringReplace(new RegExp(`<img src="([^\"]*)" style="width:([\d]*)vw" \/>`), '$2, $1'))               
        .pipe(gulp.dest('_dist/'));
}
```

*test.html* contains `<html>...<img src="/image.jpg" style="width:32vw" />...</html>`.

I get the whole regex string `<img src="/image.jpg" style="width:32vw" />`, instead of matchin parthenses output `32, /image.jpg`. Why?

EDIT: The regex seems to be ok: https://regex101.com/r/fyqCA5/1. Also tried replacing backticks, still getting the whole tag.

Comment: No replacement happened, because your regular expression doesn’t match the input. `/d` and `\d` are two completely different things.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Typo fixed. Problem prevails, though.

Comment: Possibly the backticks inside `new RegExp()`.  I would try it with just single quotes.  Plus that extension doesn't show any examples of using capture groups for some reason.  Consider using `gulp-replace` instead.